# String replace function behavior - error "nothing to repeat"

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

The below code gives the error:

```
var a = "hello {0} world";
a.replace(/{0}/g, "little");
```

But this one works:

```
var a = "hello {str} world";
a.replace(/{str}/g, "little");
```

Why do we get this error?

Answer (score 3):

Because `{n}` (with `n` being a positive integer) is *quantifier* syntax, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Quantifiers

You don’t want the curly braces to have their “special meaning” here, but want them treated as plain characters - so you should escape them.

```
a.replace(/\{0\}/g,"little")
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

The number inside a curly brace has a special meaning, it is quanitifier syntax.

#### Solution

You have to escape the curly braces with `\{ \}`

Here is an example

```js
var b = "hello {0} world"; 
console.log(b.replace(/\{0\}/g,"little"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your argument to [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) is a regular expression.

In particular, braces `{` and `}` are regular expression metacharacters (they are a range [quantifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Quantifiers)).

You must escape (with `\`) the braces in your regular expression for this to work.

For example, this:

```
a.replace(/\{0\}/g, "little");
```

would work. This would treat the braces literally.

The specific error message you get:

> SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /{0}/: Nothing to repeat

is because the engine expects some text to precede the quantifier, so for example, `x{0}` would be a valid argument as a regular expression.

In the other case, using

```
a.replace(/{str}/g, "little");
```

does work, since the braces lose their special meaning as metacharacters, and get treated literally. Range quantifiers must take the form `{n}`, `{n,}` or `{n,m}` where `n` and `m` are integers.